# Calculate same items with different amount

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

I want to know what coding looks like if I have a case like this:

I have 3 item to buy (it's like cashier application):

- Item A
- Item B
- Item C

case :

- If I buy item A more than 3 I got discount 10% for item A.
- If amount of item A and B more than 3 I got 5% discount for total of these 2 items.
- if I buy item A more 3 or item C more than 2 I got 7% discount for total payment.

What I know is like this but it doesn't work:

```
if (itemA > 3)
{
    total1=itemA-itemA*10/100;
    total=total1+itemB+itemC;
}
if (itemA+itemB > 3)
{
    total2=(itemA-itemA*5/100)+(itemB-itemB*5/100);
    total=total2+itemC;
}
if (itemA > 3 || itemC > 2);
{
    total=itemA+itemB+itemC*7/100;
}
```

Comment: Is `itemA` the number of Item As or their price?

Comment: @Zippy That edit actually made it worse, I reverted to the edit Biffen made (probably due to starting the edit before Biffen had applied his).

Comment: Be aware of integer division.  With integer division, 1/2 == 0.  With floating point, 1.0/2.0 == 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the total without any discounts and then adding on all applicable discounts. So as pseudo code:

```
total = num_a*price_a + num_b*price_b +num_c*price_c;
if (num_a > 3) 
{
    total -= discount for a.
}

if (num_a + num_b > 3) 
{
    total -= discount for b.
}

if (num_a > 3 || num_c > 2)
{
    apply 7% discount.
}
```

And all you have to do is apply the discounts now. If you want only one discount to apply, put them in order of importance and use `else if`.